# Crontab and perl

Tags: perl, twitter, cpan

I have an issue with a Perl script and the CPAN Twitter module.

I have a script that runs speedtest, and am trying to post the result to Twitter.

I have managed to get my script running manually by running ./speedtest.pl from my user account, however when I try and run it using crontab I get an error.

I have installed [`Net::Twitter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter), [`File::HomeDir`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::HomeDir) and [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) using

```
cpanm Net::Twitter
```

etc.

(Note: no sudo) I get the following error when I run my script from my local crontab:-

```
Can't locate Net/Twitter.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
Net::Twitter module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/perl5/5.20 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/pi
/speedtest.pl line 99.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/pi/speedtest.pl line 99.
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I suspect it has something to do with where `Net::Twitter` etc ended up but I've no idea how to fix it so that crontab knows where to find it.

[`speedtest.pl` is here](http://stevewright.nz/speedtest.pl)

Comment: If you run `perl -v` which version do you get? This looks like you've got two version of perl installed. Typical culprits are `/usr/bin/perl` and `/usr/local/bin/perl` This  script has been explicitly told to use the former.

Comment: perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2)

Answer (score 1):

The Perl installation that you run from the command line is different from the one run by the system when a crontab job executes

Try `which perl`, and then look at the output of the same command run under cron

There are a few ways to fix this, depending on the configuration of your system. The most obvious is to use the full path to your own copy of perl, but while that will probably get things going it is probably a bad idea

Comment: So what do I do?  run from the user account `which perl` gives me `/usr/bin/perl ` but I have no idea how to fix this?  Not sure how to look at it with cron

Comment: Change the  script - put `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`. Or `/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell` and install the library you need in the the site perl.

Comment: `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` at the top of the file gives me `-bash: ./speedtest.pl: /usr/bin/local/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` when I run the file with `./speedtest.pl`. `/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell` followed by `install Net::Twitter, tells me 'Net::Twitter is up to date (4.01020)`.

Comment: `sudo find / -name Twitter.pm` gives:- 
`/home/pi/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Twitter.pm`
`/home/pi/.cpanm/work/1467024190.19006/Net-Twitter-4.01020/lib/Net/Twitter.pm`
`/home/pi/.cpanm/work/1467024190.19006/Net-Twitter-4.01020/blib/lib/Net/Twitter.pm`

Comment: Added `use lib '/home/pi/perl5/lib/perl5/';` before `use Net::Twitter` seems to make it run with crontab,  I suspect that this is not the right way to do it but it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have installed Net::Twitter using your local account.
Logging into root & installing the module should fix this problem.